# How can I preview the scorm zip file directly in the learning platform I developed?

Tags: javascript

How can I preview the scorm zip file directly in the learning platform I developed?
I am currently developing an online learning platform, and currently there are scorm zip resources that need to be displayed in the platform. Please tell me how to preview this courseware.

I need to understand how this zip needs to be processed and how to display it on the front end.

Comment: You probably want to read the SCORM standard document [the CAM doc] from the ADL [and probably the runtime too] https://adlnet.gov/past-projects/scorm/